# Geometry package page dimensions do not scale properly

Tags: header-footer, geometry, dimensions, textwidth, textheight

I am trying to create a latex document on overleaf web editor, there are fixed requirements for the dimensions of the document and when I use the geometry package and set those dimensions and then print it out and measure those values, there is a discrepancy between them. This is how I have gone about it.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    portrait,
    ignoreall,
    heightrounded,
    paperwidth=210mm, 
    paperheight=297mm, 
    textwidth=161.5mm, 
    textheight=231mm,
    left=24.5mm,
    right=24mm,
    top=42mm,
    bottom=24mm,
    headsep=10mm, headheight=20mm,
    footskip=7mm,
    showframe
    ]{geometry}
```

and the measured dimensions for this code is

```
textwidth=156.5mm, 
    textheight=220mm,
    left=29mm,
    right=29.5mm,
    top=50mm,
    bottom=27mm,
    headsep=9.5mm, headheight=19mm,
    footskip=6.5mm.
```

```
Any help is appreciated.
```

Comment: HAve you checked no scaling takes place on printing?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but your geometry settings look a bit overspecified. If you specify the paper, you shouldn't need to also specify the paperwidth/height. And if you specify both the left and right margin, geometry can figure out the text width.

Comment: Add `verbose` to get more information on the terminal/in the log. What happens if you use `article` rather than the KOMA version?

Comment: look in the log-file. geometry is actually warning you: ``Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `h'-direction. `width' (459.512pt) is ignored.`` and similar for the v-direction.